# What is this swift declaration doing?

Tags: swift

According to the author of [this page](http://breckinloggins.blogspot.pt/2014/06/swifts-dictionary-type-is-surprising.html) this is declaring a dictionary of dictionaries in swift:

```
var routeMap : Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, () -> ()>> = [:]
```

can you explain what are this doing, specially the part with these hieroglyphs `() -> ()>> = [:]` at the end?

It appears that the guy is joining a series of commands together. If this is the case, if you can unfold that code into several lines I appreciate.

thanks.

Comment: looks like a dictionary of dictionaries of functions (with no parameters or return values) that is being initialized as empty.

Comment: This is why I already hate Swift. This is ugly and hard to read. If this is the kind of clever code culture that Swift will bring us, I want no part of it. I can reserve that for Regular Expression world.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's start at the way end.

```
[:]
```

This is simply initializing an empty Dictionary. It is very similar to calling `""` to initialize an empty String, or `[]` to initialize an empty Array.

Now, let's jump to the type declaration.

```
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, () -> ()>>
```

This is a dictionary that maps Strings to Dictionaries. Let's look closer at the type of those inner dictionaries.

```
Dictionary<String, () -> ()>
```

This maps a String to a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Closures.html). A closure is pretty much just a block from Objective C. That's what the `() -> ()` means. Let's dive deeper.

```
() -> ()
```

This is the syntax for declaring a closure. The left value are the parameters. The right are the return types. In this case, we have one parameter, and one return type.

```
()
```

This means `void` in Swift. In fact, in Swift.h, we can see this on line 3953:

```
typealias Void = ()
```

So ultimately, we have a closure that gives no (void) parameters, and has no (void) return value.

Some more examples of closures might help understand the syntax. Let's imagine a closure that takes a String and converts it to an int. The type would look like this:

```
let stringToInt: (String) -> (Int) = ...
```

Now, one with a void input. Let's have a random number generator:

```
let randomDouble: () -> (Double) = ...
```

This takes no inputs, and returns a Double.

Finally, let's have a void to void.

```
let printHelloWorld: () -> () = ...
```

You can see this takes no arguments and returns nothing. It's more of a method than a function, but it can still do stuff, like modify properties, or in this case, print to the console.

Comment: ahhhhh, now we are talking. To translate that, the guy has a dictionary of blocks! Two things: 1) suppose he does something like `let myDict = routeMap["aaa"]` and `aaa` is a valid key on that dictionary. Now he has another dictionary. Suppose that now he does `let myBlock = myDict["bbb"] abd `bbb` is a valid key on that other dictionary. Now he has a block. How he runs the block now? In objC he would do `myBlock();`. What about Swift?

Comment: Exactly! And in Swift, you'd do the exact same thing. The syntax is the same.

Comment: In fact, in Swift, functions are simply a special case of closures (blocks). So executing a function is the same syntax as executing a closure. Just call the symbol with `()` after (and parameters inside if needed).

Comment: fantastic. THANKS for the amazing explanation!